# Datagridview's Combobox to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want DatagridviewComboboxcell selected value to send it into a textbox i'm trying this for DatagridviewTextboxCell and it works but for DatagridviewComboboxcell doesnt work.

```
textBox1.Text = "" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString() + "";
```

Comment: _but for DatagridviewComboboxcell doesnt work_ tell us nothing. Please describe what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Come on man.? It so difficult to understand? For any other Datagridview's cell which is not combobox bring me the disired value to my textbox. Wen i try with the same code bring it to textbox it doesnt bring nothing. no errors but my textbox remains empty

Comment: Should i convert it to string or something? Or i use the wrong coding?

Comment: _Wen i try with the same code bring it to textbox it doesnt bring nothing. no errors but my textbox remains empty_ - add ti to the question. Are you sure that you using correct index for the `Cells[9]`?

Comment: `textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();` Should work. If no exceptions thrown, then value in the first row and 10th column is empty string. May be you can provide a code how you add items to the `DataGridViewComboBox`?

Answer (score -2):

Solved:

```
 int columnIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell Column10 = dataGridView1[9, rowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        String text = Column10.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = text;
```